# Scripting language interpreter source code to learn from

Tags: c++, c, scripting, interpreter

I want to read, and learn from, the source code of a scripting language's interpreter/compiler. What scripting language interpreter/compiler has the simplest, cleanest, and easiest to read source code? I would prefer it to be written in C/C++ (what else are compilers written in anyway?) because I'm planning on writing a compiler in C.

Comment: Try the one you like the most.

Comment: It seems quite a few people have mis-interpreted the question. Please read again :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [lua](http://www.lua.org/), you can go through the firsts versions of the programming language and see how it has evolved. It's written in C and has a clean and nice code. You can write a compiler in almost every programming language, but C has been the one that most programmers chose.

Comment: You can get the source code for all versions in one package at http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-all.tar.gz. They all compile fine.

Comment: The source code for some recent versions of Lua can be browsed with links at http://www.lua.org/source/. See also http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaSource.

Answer (score 6):

The [CPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) interrupter has been around for quite some time and I would imagine that it would be very useful to you.

Comment: The question asker was not clear about what he/she wanted. Now that he/she has clarified, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

[AngelScript](http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/) is a very good option for learning about compilers. This is a language with C/C++ familiar syntax, garbage collection, it is object-oriented with inheritance and polymorphism, cross-platform and compiles to byte-code.

My second choice would be [Lua](http://www.lua.org/).

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend, as a gentle introduction, having a look at the [LLVM Tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/).

Chris Lattner creates a simple toy language *Kaleidoscope* to show the various phases of compilation:

- [Lexing](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl1.html)
- [Parsing](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl2.html)
- [Code Generation](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html)

He then demonstrates how to [add JIT capabilities](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl4.html) (essential for an interpreter).

The toy language is extremely simple, and thus the resulting code is simple as well, and demonstrates nicely the architecture without drowning you in implementation details.

I am not sure that the tutorial is fully up-to-date and can be used as is against a recent LLVM version, but I do advise at least reading it.

(And of course, reading the [Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on V8 for JavaScript. Every interpeter has a component called tokenizer. GNU has one whose name is bison. Take on look on it too. It can be helpful. Chromium uses some tokenizer for interpreting html on the Webkit too, but V8 is the javascript interpreter.

Claudio M. Souza Junior

Answer (score 0):

a famous language, but not simple (PHP Source Code).
You can take advantage of the source code .

[PHP Source Code](http://php.net/downloads.php)

Comment: Given that 'simple' is the OP's _primary_ criteria, if the PHP source isn't simple then how is this an answer?

Comment: @ildjarn: PHP Source Code not simple, but you can benefit from Source Code even a few